# Can any Hilbert space be expressed as countable union of unit balls?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

I was going through functional analysis text by J.Conway, and have encountered with next claim (2.4.6) :

> Let $T\in \mathcal{B}_0(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{K})$ for two Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H},\mathcal{K}$. Since $\text{cl}[T(\text{ball } \mathcal{H})]$ is compact, it is separable. Therefore $\text{cl}(\text{ran} T)$ is separable subspace of $\mathcal{K}$. Here, ball $\mathcal{H}$ is closed unit ball in $\mathcal{H}$.

However, I am not convinced since this presumes that any Hilbert space can be expressed as a countable union of unit balls, which is not very trivial for me.

1. Is this claim well-known fact?
2. If so, how do you prove it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not being claimed that $\mathcal{H}$ is a countable union of unit balls (that is not true if $\mathcal{H}$ is not separable!).  Rather, what is being used here is that $\mathcal{H}$ is the union of the balls of radius $n$ around $0$. Since $T$ is linear, the images of those balls will just be scaled versions of the images of the unit balls, and therefore their images will also be separable.

Comment: Now that's clear. Thank you for clearing up!

Answer (score 2):

Not in general. This is true if and only if $\mathcal{H}$ is separable. Certainly if $\mathcal{H}$ is separable, then simply union unit balls centred at a countable dense set will produce all of $\mathcal{H}$.

Conversely, if $\mathcal{H}$ is a countable union of unit balls, then by scaling appropriately, it is a countable union of any $\frac{1}{n}$-radius balls. If you union all the centres of all the $\frac{1}{n}$ radius balls, for each $n \in \Bbb{N}$, then you get a countable dense subset, proving $\mathcal{H}$ is separable.

All that said, I don't think this is what's being claimed here. It looks like $\operatorname{ball} \mathcal{H}$ refers to "the unit ball", meaning the closed ball, centred at $0$, radius $1$.